# How to get complex types from WSDL file?

Tags: java, wsdl, complextype

I have the following wsdl file:

```
 <wsdl:types>
  <schema elementFormDefault="qualified" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
   <import namespace="http:..."/>
   <complexType name="BaseBean">
    <sequence/>
   </complexType>
   <complexType name="DateBean">
    <complexContent>
     <extension base="impl:BaseBean">
      <sequence>
       <element name="date" nillable="true" type="xsd:dateTime"/>
      </sequence>
     </extension>
    </complexContent>
   </complexType>
  </schema>
 </wsdl:types>
```

Using `WSDL4J`, I can get the `wsdl:types` node:

```
WSDLReader reader = WSDLFactory.newInstance().newWSDLReader();
Definition definition = reader.readWSDL("file.wsdl");
Types types = definition.getTypes();
```

But I cannot figure out how to get the `complex types` inside the `types`.

How can I get the complex types programatically? Where can I find an example on how do do it?

Answer (score 0):

Try doing:

```
Schema schema = null;
for (Object e : types.getExtensibilityElements()) {
    if (e instanceof Schema) {
        schema = (Schema)e;
        break;
    }
}
if (schema != null) {
    Element schemaElement = schema.getElement();
    // ...
}
```

At this point, you really only get an `org.w3c.dom.Element` instance that represents the schema.

Comment: tried this before. it returns a strange [schema: null] reference.

Comment: @Paulo - but did you actually try doing anything with the Element besides printing it? Like, what does `schemaElement.hasChildNodes()` return?

Comment: `hasChildNodes()` returns `true`.  but the `schema.getElement()` itself returns an object whose attributes are `elementFormDefault="qualified" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"` but no way to grab the complex types. :/

Comment: @Paulo - clearly that depends on what you mean by "grab the complex types". another option would be to process the wsdl with a tool like wsimport to generate jaxb classes for your schema types. see the jax-ws ri at: https://jax-ws.dev.java.net/

Comment: I mean, I would like to have something like `getComplexTypes()` for example. I need to iterate over the complex types inside the schema. External tools are not useful for me, I need to do this programatically.

Comment: @PauloGuedes Do you remember how you have solved this issue ? Thanks